# Override die in Perl and still return correct exit code on Windows

Tags: perl

On Windows, I want to execute something only when the script dies.
Below block didn't help; I think it's because Windows don't support signals.

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    qx(taskkill /F /IM telnet.exe);
    CORE::die @_;
}
```

Then I tried this:

```
END {
    qx(taskkill /F /IM telnet.exe);
    exit $exit_code;
}
```

It performed `taskkill`, but exited with exit code 0.  I need to propagate `exit_code` as we do further processing based on it.

Comment: `$SIG{__DIE__}` isn't a real signal. It works perfectly on all platforms. It gets called when an exception is thrown.

Comment: but I do see it's not working on Windows, I use Perl 5.18.

Comment: What's not working on Windows? `$SIG{__DIE__}`? Again, it works fine. If you try `perl -e"$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { warn('Foo: ', @_); exit(123); }; die 'bar'"`, you'll see `Foo:` prepended to the error message, and if you follow up with `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`, you'll see `123`.

Comment: Thanks ikegami for taking time to help on this, As I mentioned in my original question above, I tried `$SIG{__DIE__}` and added a "die"  command in the script to verify, it didn't execute `taskkill`

Comment: No, really, it works. I've already demonstrated that it works. And there's nothing stopping you from using backticks in a `__DIE__` handler. `perl -e"$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { warn(\`echo Foo\`, @_); exit(123); }; die 'bar'"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`END` blocks can set `$?` to control the exit value.

```
END {
      qx(taskkill /F /IM telnet.exe);
      $? = $exit_code;
}
```